# How can I make a part of my mesh more round after it's already made?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I bought this model of a microscope but noticed the eye piece is not perfectly round, you can see its made of sides, how can i make it perfectly round? I tried Subdividing but that only increases the poly count but the shape stays the same! checking smoothing also doesnt affect it. Is it possible?

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show the mesh in wireframe mode?  I think you're going to have to remodel it but hard to say without seeing what you've got.

Comment: Sure, I added an image of the wireframe above.

Comment: You can just add a Subdivision Surface modifier. To avoid it rounding the ends you will have to make additional loops, try and let us know how you get one. Love the render by the way, great dirt/scuff material.

Comment: Thanks, Subdivision Surface modifier does the trick. Setting it to 2 gives me a perfectly round eyepiece.